# Read content of a joomla plugin from remote site

Tags: joomla, remote-access, virtuemart

I have Joomla CMS and use Virtuemart plugin to sale some products.
I want to sale same products that another site sales.

Please help me to read from remote or copy to local.

***I never want to you do my project I just your guidance.***

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of VM you're using, but the database for products in VM is quite extensive, so I would be *very* surprised if this was possible.  I've done scores of import projects for VM, and have always needed the non-visible values of the database for the products to have active products on our sites.